Should I say "Something good already happened" or "Something good has already happened"?
the following is an excerpt from "A Crazy Day with Cobras" by Mary Pope Osborne

A warm breeze blew through the leaves on the newly green trees.
“I love it,” said Annie. “It makes me feel like something good’s going to happen.”
“Something good already happened,” said Jack. “My teacher finally gave back my story today.”

Should Jack say "Something good already happened" or "Something good has already happened"?

What leads you to believe the sentence as written is wrong? In what way is it wrong? What research have you done to resolve the question yourself? And what did that research uncover?

The author is American, and this is American usage. A British author would have been more likely to use the perfect tense.


It makes me feel like something good’s going to happen.


"Something good already happened,”
said Jack. “My teacher finally gave back my story today.”

The simple past is fine; the happening (or giving) was treated just as a past event.
The present perfect is fine too.  The event was still relevant at the time of speaking, that is, to the topic something good’s going to happen.
